# Drag event on mxGraph overlay

Tags: mxgraph

I have inserted an overlay on the image node using the following code

```
function addOverlay(vertex,graph) {
    var imgo = new mxImage("images/collapsed.gif",11,11);
    var overlay = new mxCellOverlay(imgo,"",
            mxConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT,mxConstants.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
            new mxPoint(1, 1),mxConstants.CURSOR_TERMINAL_HANDLE);
    graph.addCellOverlay(vertex, overlay);

    // Installs a handler for clicks on the overlay
    overlay.addListener( mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, evt2) {
        var cell = evt2.getProperty('cell');
        var state = graph.view.getState(cell);
        graph.connectionHandler.start(state, 1, 1);
        graph.isMouseDown = true;
        graph.isMouseTrigger = true;
        mxEvent.consume(evt2);
   });
}
```

This functionality works creates node as shown in the image below

[image: node with overlay]

Now on a click on the overlay the edges are added properly by connecting it to the required vertex, 
  but I would like to draw the edges by dragging on the overlay.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overrride mxCellRenderer.installCellOverlayListeners as follows:

```
graph.cellRenderer.installCellOverlayListeners = function(state, 
    overlay, shape)
{
  mxEvent.addGestureListeners(shape.node, function(evt)
  {
    graph.connectionHandler.start(state, 1, 1);
    graph.isMouseDown = true;
    graph.isMouseTrigger = true;
    mxEvent.consume(evt);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is solving my case